# Vue CLI y Vuetify: Cambiar background-color de <th> específico en una <v-data-table>

Tags: vuetify, vue-cli

Tengo una `v-data-table` con estos headers:

```
computed:{
    empleadosHeaders() {
      return [
        { text: "Nº", value: "n", class: "text-no-wrap sticky-header text-center", sortable: false, align: "center" },
        { text: "NOMBRE", value: "nombre", class: "text-no-wrap sticky-header text-center", align: "center" },
        { text: "APELLIDOS", value: "apellidos", class: "text-no-wrap sticky-header text-center", align: "center" },
        { text: "ANTIGÜEDAD", value: "antiguedad", dataType: "select", class: "text-no-wrap sticky-header text-center", align: "center" },
        { text: "BRUTO ANUAL", value: "brutoAnual", class: "text-no-wrap sticky-header" },
        { text: "DEPARTAMENTO", value: "departamento", class: "text-no-wrap sticky-header" },
        { text: "RESPONSABILIDAD", value: "responsabilidad", class: "text-no-wrap sticky-header" },
        { text: "CONVERSACIONES", value: "conversaciones", class: "text-no-wrap sticky-header text-center infoBg" },
        { text: "REUNIONES DPTO", value: "reunionesDpto", class: "text-no-wrap sticky-header text-center info--text infoBg" },
        { text: "FORMACIÓN", value: "formacion", class: "text-no-wrap sticky-header text-center success--text successBg" },
        { text: "ENCUESTAS", value: "encuestas", class: "text-no-wrap sticky-header text-center success--text successBg" },
        { text: "BAJAS", value: "bajas", class: "text-no-wrap sticky-header text-center error--text errorBg" },
        { text: "PERMISOS", value: "permisos", class: "text-no-wrap sticky-header text-center error--text errorBg" },
        { text: "AMONESTACIONES", value: "indisciplinas", class: "text-no-wrap sticky-header text-center error--text errorBg" },
        { text: "OTROS", value: "otros", class: "text-no-wrap sticky-header text-center error--text errorBg" },
      ]
      .filter(
        (h) =>
          (h.acceso == null || this.$root.acceso(h.acceso))
      )
      .map((header) => ({
        cellClass: "pa-1 text-no-wrap",
        filter: (value) =>
          perColumnFilter(
            value,
            this.inlineFilters[header.value],
            header.dataType
          ),
        dataType: "text",
        ...header,
      }));
    }
  },
```

En `conversaciones`, `reunionesDpto`... tengo las clases `infoBg`, `successBg` y `errorBg` con estos estilos:

```
<style>
.infoBg{
  color: black !important;
  background-color: rgba(33, 150, 243, .2) !important;
}
.successBg{
  background-color: rgba(76, 175, 80, .2) !important;
}
.errorBg{
  background-color: rgba(255, 82, 82, .2) !important;
}
</style>
```

En `conversaciones`, si quito la clase `info--text` para que pueda poner un color desde la clase `infoBg`, me pone el texto en negro, pero no cambia el color de fondo. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

Cómo está ahora (con el `info--text` quitado para comprobar que está cogiendo la clase `infoBg`):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como debería estar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

De momento lo he solucionado creando el slot `header` manualmente, y encadenando varios `?`:

```
<template v-slot:header="{ props: { headers } }">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th v-for="h,i in headers" :class="h.class" :style="(h.class.indexOf('infoBg') != -1 ? 'background-color: rgba(33, 150, 243, .2) !important;' : (h.class.indexOf('successBg') != -1 ? 'background-color: rgba(76, 175, 80, .2) !important;' : (h.class.indexOf('errorBg') != -1 ? 'background-color: rgba(255, 82, 82, .2) !important;' : '')))">
                <span>{{h.text}}</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</template>
```

Creo que es algo bastante chapucero, si alguien sabe alguna forma de hacerlo más elegante, lo marcaré como respuesta en vez de esto.